# Can't tell if the SettingWithCopy warning is accurate

Tags: python, pandas

```
def nan_to_zeros(df, col):
    new_col = f"nanreplace{col}"
    df[new_col] = df[col].fillna('~')
    return df
```

When running this function I get the
`SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`
warning and from what I can gather I am not using a chained assignment and adding `inplace=True` does nothing to silence the warning.

Any direction appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your df reference is probably to a view into a larger dataframe. As long as you're not throwing away that reference you don't have to worry.

Comment: Note if `df` was ever subset unsafely at _any point before_ being passed to this function you will get a `SettingWithCopyWarning` even if one is not created within the function itself. You want to look for lines of code like: `new_df = df[cols]` or `new_df = df[mask]` or in this case even `nan_to_zeros(df[mask], 'col_name')` has the potential to raise this warning.